# How to find if any array elements are larger than a certain value using `arrayfun`

Tags: arrays, matlab

Let's say we have an array `numbers`. If any elements in the array are greater than 3, I want to make `array` equal `nan`.

```
array = [1 2 3 4 5];

if arrayfun(@greater than 3,array)
    array = nan;
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need arrayfun for this simple job. `if any(array > 3); array = nan; end` is all you need.